# Proof of $\Bbb R^n \not\eqsim \Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology

> [image]

Why is showing the same space but without a point is equivalent to show that the original spaces are not homemorphic? From what i could tell they just showed $\Bbb R - \{ x \} \not\eqsim \Bbb R^n - \{ x \}$, but these are different spaces from the question no?

Comment: A general answer can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234001/a-b-homemorphic-to-c-d-cup-h-k)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $f \colon X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then for every $A\subset X$, the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is a homeomorphism between $A$ and $f(A)$.

Proof: Let $g\colon Y \to X$ be the inverse of $f$. Then $g$ is continuous, and hence so is its restriction to $f(A)$, but $g\lvert_{f(A)} = \left(f\lvert_A\right)^{-1}$, so $f\lvert_A$ is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse.

So if $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ were (for $n > 1$) a homeomorphism, it would induce a homeomorphism $\tilde{f} \colon \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}\setminus \{f(0)\}$. Since these spaces are not homeomorphic, such an $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: Can you provide me a proof of the first statement? It isn't entirely obvious to me it is true. I can only "see" continuity, but the rest isn't so clear.

Comment: Let $g = f^{-1}$. By assumption, $g$ is continuous. Hence $g\lvert_{f(A)}$ is also continuous, as the restriction of a continuous function to a subspace. But $g\lvert_{f(A)} = \left(f\lvert_A\right)^{-1}$. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: No, no, no, by 'rest' i mean bijectivity. But include continuity anyways in case my intuition is off.

Comment: Actually, I just wrote some stuff down and proved the result. I did each property separately, unlike yours. Are there any "geometric" intuition to help me remember this? Relating to calculus/analysis would be easiest to remember

Comment: By "this" in "help me remember this", what do you mean? That the restriction of homeomorphisms to subsets induces a homeomorphism between the subset and its image?

Comment: yeah that's what I mean.

Comment: Hmmm. I can't think of any geometric intuition, at least not now. But that restriction of maps preserves injectivity is clear (it can even make non-injective maps injective), so the restriction of an injective map to a subset $A$ is a bijection between $A$ and its image $f(A)$. That restriction of maps preserves continuity is pretty much the definition of the subspace topology. So together with "the inverse of a restriction is a restriction of the inverse", everything is there.